# html: I have three columns but everything should be in two columns

Tags: html, css

This html code "Date Accessed" is in one column (at the top as a header), while the actual dates are in another column, but they're all supposed to be in one column. I can't figure out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Django Level Two</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyle.css" %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1> Hi welcome to Django Level Two <h1>
  <h2> Here are your access records:<h2>

  <div class="djangtwo">
    {% if access_records %}
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>Site Name</th>
        <th>Date Accessed</th>
      </thead>

      {% for acc in access_records %}
    </tr>
        <td>{{acc.name}}<td>
        <td>{{acc.date}}<td>
      <tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </table>
      {% else %}
      <p>NO ACCESS RECORDS </p>
      {% endif %}

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the problem is not in the .css file but here it is anyways

```
h1{
  color: red;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated-thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<tr>` start/end tags are the wrong way round, they should look like this. Also added correct end tags for `<td>` elements.

```
<tr>
  <td>{{acc.name}}</td>
  <td>{{acc.date}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ah that fixed the problem! ty!

Comment: @JohnHarbaugh no problem! Would you mind accepting this as the "best" answer? Thanks!

Comment: idk how to accept it as the best answer, i did accept it...